# JS call to Secure Spring Boot Rest API is failing

Tags: javascript, spring, amazon-web-services, rest

My application is hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have some java scripts consuming the Rest APIs. When I try to call them through a custom domain, I get this error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at
'https://myspringbootapp-env.eba-z84eerdv.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/getAllEbs'
from origin 'https://www.mydomain.in' has been blocked by CORS policy:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

If I try to access from my aws environment linkhttps://myspringbootapp-env.eba-z84eerdv.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/ , it works perfectly.

I have added @CrossOrigin annotation on my rest controller.

Comment: Since you can access the API in a different environment, it's probably not a CORS issue. You get this message whenever there is no CORS header, including no response at all :)

Comment: Hi @k-wasilewski, Thanks for your response.

Actually, this application is hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. And when I try to access this through the environment link, it works fine. But it's not working when I try to fetch it through a custom domain.

Comment: @k-wasilewski, this issue comes up when I access it through chrome. When I try to access it through edge, I get ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error.

Comment: I really can't help you, as I've no exp with AWS. I just know that indeed Chrome blocks CORS requests and you can enable it somewhere...